# Coproduct of injective modules

Tags: category-theory, injective-module

I read many papers that looked for sufficient conditions for coproduct of injective modules to be injective modules, but I didn't find the reason why they always look for this. I want to know the philosophy of why the coproduct of injective modules is so important. I know from category theory that coproduct of a collection of objects in a category is the best fit that injects the whole objects without "shrinking" and "collapsing". Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: It's not *so* important.  It's one of thousands of mildly interesting questions with occasional applications that mathematicians have studied.

Comment: To construct new objects one way is to take coproducts. So if you already understand a number of easier injective modules, it would be nice if taking their coproduct yields another injective module, so we can build new coproducts. The same thing appears often: Is the product/coproduct of Lie groups inside the category of smooth manifolds again a Lie group? Is the coproduct of nice (insert any property for schemes) schemes again nice? Is the coproduct of abelian groups inside the category of groups again an abelian group? Etc etc.

Comment: I may be mistaken about the context here but (for rings with identity at least) it has been characterized that an arbitrary coproduct of injective right modules is injective iff the ring is right Noetherian.  I thought this was pretty classical and I would be surprised there's "many papers looking for sufficient conditions," unless they were assuming a broader context than the one I've just described.

Comment: As for the implied question "why is it interesting?" well, it is always fairly interesting to investigate the stability or interaction of interesting conditions with interesting constructions, and that's what's going on here.